# To check a situatoin : "... , it is checked whether ..."

Tags: phrase-choice

I have this sentence (However you may find it technical):

> If it matches any of the anchors, the anchor is marked as visited. If there is a context which is defined over this anchor, **it is checked whether** the beginning or ending of this context can be marked with this anchor or not.

is it a natural way to say about the investigation of a situation to determine something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The passive construction "is defined over" is not quite natural, nor is it perfectly clear.  Normally we'd say

**if the anchor *belongs to* a context**

Also, the passive constructions "it is checked" and "can be marked with" are clearer and simpler if recast in the active:

**...we check whether the anchor marks the beginning or ending of the context.**